# Django implementing rate for post

Tags: django

Currently I have these models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')

    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    post_content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    .
    .
    .

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_title

class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post')
    vote_type = models.SmallIntegerField()
    date_voted = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

I use this query to find all the posts:

```
def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(created_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-created_date')
    return render(request, 'homepage/index.html', {'posts': posts})
```

But this only returns the posts. I also want the Votes related to each post. Is there some way to join these two models with query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each post `p` in the `posts` queryset will have access to its related `Vote` objects through `p.vote_set.all()` - you can access that in the template as well as in the view.

Comment: Another question: what is the proper way of checking if current user has voted for this post or not? Should I use template tags and query the database for each post and check if the user has voted? Isn't this heavy task? or is there some better approaches?

Comment: It would be best to post this as a separate question in accordance with StackOverflow guidelines. If you choose to do so, feel free to let me know and I'll try to answer.